# Multiple Countdown Timer Buttons on one page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I want to set up mutiple countdown timer buttons on a single page. I'm also trying to change the buttons color when clicked (turns green to red when clicked) and refresh the color and timer display when the timer reached to zero.

I can do it with just one timer but when try to run the second, it doesnt work.

Here the codes that I used. (Please keep in mind, I'm just a beginner :)

```
var running = false;
var endTime = null;
var timerID = null;

function startTimer() {
    running = true;
    now = new Date();
    now = now.getTime(); 
    // change last multiple for the number of minutes
    endTime = now + (1000 * 60 * 680);
    showCountDown();
}


function showCountDown() {
    var now = new Date();
    now = now.getTime();
    if (endTime - now <= 0) {
        stopTimer()


    } else {
        var delta = new Date(endTime - now);
        var theMin = delta.getMinutes();
        var theSec = delta.getSeconds();
        var theHour = delta.getHours();
        var theTime = theHour 
        theTime += ((theMin < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + theMin;
        theTime += ((theSec < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + theSec;
        document.forms[0].timerDisplay1.value = theTime;
        if (running) {
            timerID = setTimeout("showCountDown()",1000);
            document.getElementById("startTime1").style.backgroundColor = "RED";
            document.getElementById("timerDisplay1").style.backgroundColor = "RED";
            document.forms[0].startTime1.value = "WAIT";
        }
    }
}



function stopTimer() {
    clearTimeout(timerID)
    running = false;
    document.forms[0].timerDisplay1.value = "13:20:00";
    document.getElementById("timerDisplay1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    document.getElementById("startTime1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    document.forms[0].startTime1.value = "START";
}
```

This works fine, but after I add for the codes below for second timer,it doesnt work. I changed the function and variable names (no idea if it is necessary) but doesnt help anything.

```
function startTimer2() {
    running2 = true;
    now2 = new Date();
    now2 = now2.getTime(); 
    // change last multiple for the number of minutes
    endTime2 = now2 + (1000 * 60 * 680);
    showCountDown2();
}



function stopTimer2() {
    clearTimeout(timerID2)
    running2 = false;
    document.forms[0].timerDisplay2.value = "13:20:00";
    document.getElementById("timerDisplay2").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    document.getElementById("startTime2").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    document.forms[0].startTime2.value = "START";
    }

    function showCountDown2() {
    var now2 = new Date();
    now2 = now2.getTime();
    if (endTime2 - now2 <= 0) {
        stopTimer2()


    } else {
        var delta2 = new Date(endTime2 - now2);
        var theMin2 = delta2.getMinutes();
        var theSec2 = delta2.getSeconds();
        var theHour2 = delta2.getHours();
        var theTime2 = theHour2 
        theTime2 += ((theMin2 < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + theMin2;
        theTime2 += ((theSec2 < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + theSec2;
        document.forms[0].timerDisplay2.value = theTime2;
        if (running2) {
            timerID2 = setTimeout("showCountDown2()",1000);
            document.getElementById("startTime2").style.backgroundColor = "RED";
            document.getElementById("timerDisplay2").style.backgroundColor = "RED";
            document.forms[0].startTime2.value = "WAIT";
        }
    }
}
```

And HTML side;

```
<FORM>
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
<INPUT TYPE="button" ID="startTime1" VALUE="START" onClick="startTimer()"</a>

<INPUT TYPE="text" ID="timerDisplay1" VALUE="13:20:00">
</FORM>

<FORM>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">
<INPUT TYPE="button" ID="startTime2" VALUE="START" onClick="startTimer2()"</a>

<INPUT TYPE="text" ID="timerDisplay2" VALUE="01:00:00">
</FORM>
```

Comment: You have 2 <form> blocks yet in your showCountDown2() method you refer to the first form 'document.forms[0]'. Try referring to 'document.forms[1]' and see if that helps?

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you so much Nick :)